# 'rel=nofollow' in Profile links

Tags: discussion, profile-page, hyperlinks, external-links

I was looking around at a couple of profiles on Stack Overflow today and I noticed certain users have different links connected to their profile's `url`.

For instance if you go to my profile you will see

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" rel="nofollow me" class="url">example.com</a>
```

However if you go to a higher rep user (I'm guessing?) you will get

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="me" class="url">example.com</a>
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The idea is that *without* the [`nofollow`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow), the Stack Overflow profile page counts as a link to the target website in Google's PageRank algorithm (and similar algorithms in other search engines). So if you are an established user, you can use that fact to improve the SEO of your website just a little bit.

The threshold for this privilege is [2000 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11358/295232), but it is not mentioned in the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: That was my hunch! Thanks for the info I was wondering what the cap would be:) I think that would be a good thing to add to that list honestly.

Comment: Yet another undocumented privilege!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/55860/295232) (sort of).

Comment: Meh I don't really count a list of undocumented features as documentation ;)

Comment: This ambiguity certainly had me questioning things and even looking at source code, given [this conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386322/get-backlink-stack-exchange-for-seo/386323#comment1288287_386323) could you add clarity here to specify that it is links from the form fields in profile edit only, and not all the links you might add to the about me section? (Jeff's answer certainly makes it clear that this was true at one point, but folks might not follow through, or question whether it is still the case, like I did.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm confused as well. The link in the [OP's About Me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2656747/noobskie) doesn't have a `noreferrer`. It's not because it's the same link as his website link; you have that situation too, but all links in your About Me do have `noreferrer`. Bug?